# Vertically aligning an inline list within a div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to vertically align inline list elements within a div, however i cant figure out why its not working. I have included

```
.nav li{
    display: inline;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
.nav ul {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0% 6% 0% 0%;
    }
```

Help would be much appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/y1paacbh/

I see it may be unclear what is happening due to the way jsfiddle is presenting it. Here is an image from my browser
[image]

Comment: According to the picture, they are horizontally aligned, not vertically.

Comment: I am having a problem understanding your question as well. Are you wanting the list items to be displayed horizontally as shown, but aligned vertically in the div?

Answer (score 1):

By giving this styles you can fix this issue

```
  .nav li {
   position : relative;
   top : 8px;  
    }
```

Comment: May this will not help . if height increses  the above code will fails

Comment: as per the requirement we need to change the top of the element. Then that issue also will be fixed

Comment: can you post a fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Your are using two `display` property.

Use this instead

```
.nav li{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: This will cause the elements to no longer be inline though

Comment: You want list item to be aligned vertically...then why do you want them inline..?
You want them inline or vertically aligned..?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve...?

Comment: I want them inline, and then the entire (inline) list to be vertically aligned within the div. Please see the photo i added

Comment: Give your `.nav ul` some padding on top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your CSS code and insert this one.

```
.nav {
  background-color:green;
}

ul li {
  display:block;
}
```

If I helped you , please check my answer , if not , explain your problem.

Comment: This will cause the list to no longer be inline. What i need is for them to remain inline, and then vertically align the inline list

Answer (score 0):

I update view for you as follow as you need it vertically

```
<style>
.nav {
    background-color:green;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li{
    //display: inline;
    //display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.nav ul {
    vertical-align: middle;
    //display: table-cell;
    margin: 0% 6% 0% 0%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y1paacbh/1/

Comment: I updated your view in js fiddle you could check it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the effect you are after.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.nav {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30%; /* for demo purposes */
}
.nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav ul {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="navright">Home</li>
    <li class="navright">About</li>
    <li class="navright">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y1paacbh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
.nav ul{
  background-color:green;
  height: 10%;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="navright">Home</li>
    <li class="navright">About</li>
    <li class="navright">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understoud your question correctly, but in this way you can have elements:
1) vertically centered
AND
2) orizzontally distributed

```
.nav {
  background-color:green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
    }

.nav li {
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  width:33%;
  height:30px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none; /*if you want to remove bullets*/
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  display:table;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
 }
```

[working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1paacbh/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's really easy and you only need to use two rules on your parent.

```
align-items:center;
display:flex;
```

```css
ul {
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
  
  background:orange;
  height:100%;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  padding:20px;
}

.nav { height:300px; }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="navright">Home</li>
        <li class="navright">About</li>
        <li class="navright">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```